# Docusign PowerForm - Auto populate without URL parameters

Tags: docusignapi, powerform

I currently have an application that a user fills out and upon submit, the information gets saved to an Oracle database and then they're taken to a page that allows them to both upload documents and click on a link that takes them to a PowerForm for them (and one additional person that they have to specify) to fill out and sign. There is some data on the PowerForm that comes from the Oracle db and needs to be pre-populated on the form, but is sensitive data. I have seen how to send this data via the URL, but since it is sensitive data, having it in the URL is not an option. Is there another way that this information can be sent to the PowerForm? I tried playing around with having the link be a Submit button on a form and the data as hidden fields, but have not been successful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please share the code of your Form, because you can send data as POST also, and it works fine.

Comment: My form looks like this:
   <form action="https://demo.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=de44acd5-5bae-4c53-9618-39e6d79304b9" method="POST"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="GTID" id="gtid" value='123456789'/> 
  <input type="hidden" name='stu_first_name' value="Lauren" id="stu_first_name"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="stu_last_name" id="stu_last_name" value='Robinson'/>
  <input class="form_submit" type="submit" value='Click here for the Verification form.'/>
   </form>

How would I get the info from that page to the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below Form is working fine for me as `POST`, in below Powerform, `Signer1` is the `roleName` so using hidden fields I am passing `Signer1's email and Name`. Also `GTID`, `stu_first_name` and `stu_last_name` are different datalabel on the template which will get prepopulated using below code on the envelope at the time of Signing.

```
<form action="https://demo.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=cee447de-d6a3-48d5-adb3-f00e695215c9" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="GTID" id="gtid" value='123456789'/>
    <input type="hidden" name='stu_first_name' value="Lauren" id="stu_first_name"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="stu_last_name" id="stu_last_name" value='Robinson'/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Signer1_UserName" id="Signer1_UserName" value='Robinson Doe'/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Signer1_Email" id="Signer1_Email" value='email@gmail.com'/>
    <input class="form_submit" type="submit" value='Click here for the Verification form.'/>
</form>
```

Comment: You're right. My issue was that it's case sensitive. Thanks!